# How to insert DIV and SCRIPT into a page from a single HTML template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML template that includes a DIV (containing a button) and a script that will contain a function to call when that button is clicked (template.html retrieved via `$.get()` into `var text`):

```
<div id="CLC_Form">
    various text and checkbox inputs go here...
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="close_clc" value="Done" onclick="CLC_Done()" />
</div>

<script>
    function CLC_Done() {
        document.getElementById("CLC_Form").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

But in the `.get callback()`, I cannot `appendChild(text)` this HTML content to the `BODY` because it is a string, not an actual HTML element.

I could `createElement('div')` and `createElement("script")`, and insert the innerHTML for each from templates, but then my template would have to have just the innerHTML of the div and the script, without their `div` and `script` tags, which makes the template code vague as to what it is.  It would just look like "loose code", and I would have to have **two separate templates** to do it.

The page I am wanting to insert it into looks like this (index.html before):

```
<body>
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div style="clear:both; margin-bottom:32px;">
            Some stuff
        </div>
        <div id="aPanels"></div>
        <div id="bPanels"></div>
        <div id="cPanels"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the end result I am wanting to achieve looks like this (index.html after):

```
<body>
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div style="clear:both; margin-bottom:32px;">
            Some stuff
        </div>
        <div id="aPanels"></div>
        <div id="bPanels"></div>
        <div id="cPanels"></div>

        <div id="CLC_Form">
            various text and checkbox inputs go here...
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="close_clc" value="Done" onclick="CLC_Done()" />
        </div>

        <script>
            function CLC_Done() {
                document.getElementById("CLC_Form").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>

    </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to do this?  Or will I **have to** `createElement()` and set the `.innerHTML` from two separate templates?

I have jQuery available if I need it, but would prefer vanilla js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `documentFragment` and set its `innerHTML`. It doesn't exist in the DOM unless you append it, and when you do, the fragment is **replaced** by its `innerHTML` **entirely**.

```
let fragment = document.createFragment();
fragment.innerHTML = text;
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

> `DocumentFragments` are DOM Nodes. They are never part of the main DOM tree. The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append elements to the document fragment and then append the document fragment to the DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is replaced by all its children.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Comment: Hmmmn.  That's not a bad idea.  let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: Zoiks!  That actually worked - kinda.  The script is in the DOM but it doesn't seem to recognise it.  It doesn't fire when I click the button!  I think I know how to fix that, though.

Comment: Nope.  In the past, I've had good results by setting display to "none" then back on to "block" or "inline-block", which causes CSS styles to be applied.  But that didn't help with the <script>.  It doesn't recognise it.  I'll keep hacking on it.  I may just have to add that as a function in my main.js that is loaded at page load time.  Anything more, and I will PM you so we don't get busted for starting a conversation here.  ;-)  Thanks!  (EDIT: Moving that script function out to my pre-loaded main.js solved the problem.  I think I will just leave it at that and go on.)

Comment: And, hey!  I'm gonna be in Munich week after next!  ;-)